# RequiredFieldValidator in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation

Is requiredfieldvalidator in asp.net client-side validation or server-side validation? If it is a client-side, is it achieved through JavaScript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> Is requiredfieldvalidator in asp.net client-side validation or
>   server-side validation?

Both

> If it is a client-side, is it achieved through JavaScript?

Yes